# Should I Use Native Generic PHP or a Framework

Tags: php

I'm working with a team i just met.

I've been using the normal native generic php for coding up until now,
and built several webapps with it.
But a team member suggests we switch to using a framework for development.
I personally prefer going the normal way, using native generic PHP codes, 
but he Suggests we use a framework.

I learnt Code Igniter has problem with loading images,
and this is one problem with some frameworks, they have some difficulties you just have to go with, unlike writing native PHP Codes.

I have a large archive of PHP Codes, that does the work of what some Framework does,
i can use this and implement it in the WebApp.

Is it better to go with a Framework or Go Native & Generic PHP.

Another thing is that, this is a web app for mobile devices, which me and the team are developing for a company, and there will be need for maintenance in the nearest future, if we are not available for the maintenance.

Our codes has to be very simple, not too ambiguous and self explanatory, and with comments too, for the future developer. Which is why i'm thinking we write out our own codes, and make it very Simple in the best possible way.

Comment: try a microframework like slim

Answer (score 4):

This [article](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/top-10-reasons-why-you-should-use-a-php-framework) gives an overview of some reasons that you might want to use a framework. To me it sounds like you've built up your own custom framework.

Points like less code for faster development and neat and tidy code/files are good points to consider when starting from scratch.

The Job oppertunities point is one to consider for yourself and your personal development.  It's also work considering the inverse of this which is your going to appear a more desirable place to work when/if you attempt to hire on more staff.  The staff you hire will also be productive faster if they can quickly recognise the patterns in the code.

Performance and security are always good things to think about as well.

It's also worth considering if your coworker is politely trying to say that they are finding the current code base difficult to work with and would like some more predictable structure.

In conclusion my **opinion** would be yes use a framework, it'll make things easier in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

Something to add on to @Klee points, on a team member's point of view it is much better that everyone is working on the same page with a known documented framework, which might not be the case with your own archive PHP codes.

Also you might want to start converting some of your archive codes to use-able modular libraries so you/your team can readily extend the framework if similar functions are not provided.

Comment: So you're saying i should convert my archived php codes into a framework, so me and my team can use it? That's possible. I'm using PDO Fetch interface for mysql db access, and all my codes are PHP 5, but another thing is the time it will take to do this.

Answer (score 3):

A best solution for your question is to decide with your team members about this matter and which is best using a framework or Native generic programming .I suggest you to develop your own framework which contains all features your team want.

There are plenty of tutorials available i internet , see a tutsplus tutorial on php framework development :-

[**Php5 framework development**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-php5-framework-part-1/)

Comment: Sure i can do that, develop the framework. But like i told bron, another thing is the time it wil take to do this. Create classes, methods, and compile all the codes into a modular, structured framework, even available for public use.